# access denied on a jenkins build to a remote windows file server

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and I am trying to play around with it.
I'm trying to run a pipeline with a command that will run a simple `dir` on a remote windows fileserver (with a UNC path provided).

```
pipeline {
   agent any

   stages {
      stage('Read File') {
         steps {
            bat 'whoami'
            bat label: 'check directory', script: 'dir \\\\filesrv\\C$\\NewUser'

         }
      }
   }
}
```

The `whoami` command returns the Jenkins AD user i configured to run the service on the slave 
but after that I get an error `Access is denied.`

I tried giving the Jenkins AD service user local admin permission on the Jenkins master and slave servers and also on the file server. didn't help.

I also tried to explicitly giving that user full control permission on the folder I'm trying to access (located on the file server). didn't help.

I also tried giving permission to the computer accounts like many thread suggenst and point to this link https://serverfault.com/questions/135867/how-to-grant-network-access-to-localsystem-account also didn't help.

Will appreciate some assistance in understanding what permission is it missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i'll post the solution for any feature reference for those who are using windows environment...

the thing i was missing was making the target folder a shared folder.
so instead of `\\\\filesrv\\C$\\NewUser'` the path that worked is `\\\\filesrv\\NewUser'`
where `NewUser` is the name of the share